# Multiple File Download in Javascript Requires Timeout

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, download

I'd like to download multiple files at once within a browser where the file contents already exist in memory.

There are already resources that show how to do this: see this [article](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/189/how-to-create-a-file-and-generate-a-download-with-javascript-in-the-browser-without-a-server) and the [downloadjs library](https://github.com/rndme/download).

I'm able to download a single file, but not multiple when the download calls are near each other. I've attached a sample that shows three consecutive download calls where only the final file is downloaded. Below that is code that spaces the calls apart by 100ms, which does download all the files.

Why is this the case?

Thus far, I've only tested the code in Chrome.

Download function:

```
    function download(contents, filename, filetype) {
      // From: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/189/how-to-create-a-file-and-generate-a-download-with-javascript-in-the-browser-without-a-server
      var element = document.createElement('a');
      element.setAttribute('href', 'data:' + filetype + ',' + encodeURIComponent(contents));
      element.setAttribute('download', filename);
      element.style.display = 'none';
      document.body.appendChild(element);
      element.click();
      document.body.removeChild(element);
    }
```

Example usage:

```
  <button onclick="startDownload()">Click to download</button>
  <script>
    function startDownload() {
      download("hello 0", "hello0.txt", "text/plain");
      download("hello 1", "hello1.txt", "text/plain");
      // hello2.txt is the only one that downloads
      download("hello 2", "hello2.txt", "text/plain");
    }
  </script>
```

What does work is spacing the download calls apart with a `setTimeout()` call.

E.g.

```
function downloadWrapper(contents, filename, filetype, timeoutMultiplier) {
  setTimeout(
    function() {
    download(contents, filename, filetype);
  }, timeoutMultiplier * 100);
}

// All of these download; they're spaced apart by 100 ms
downloadWrapper("hello 0", "hello0.txt", "text/plain", 0);
downloadWrapper("hello 1", "hello1.txt", "text/plain", 1);
downloadWrapper("hello 2", "hello2.txt", "text/plain", 2);
```

The above workaround works, though I'm not sure why. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: Similar thing happens with fileSaver.js, which uses that technique under the hood, although for your example to work with fileSaver it is enough almost every time to use 0ms timeouts. Created an issue there https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/issues/435